# Fragment crashes on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Every time orientation changes Fragment crashes with error:

```
01-26 12:46:43.215    2895-2895/com.cbsystematic.mobile.itvdn 

E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cbsystematic.mobile.itvdn, PID: 2895
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.cbsystematic.mobile.itvdn/com.cbsystematic.mobile.itvdn.NavigationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3671)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3889)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1365)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:516)
            at com.cbsystematic.mobile.itvdn.LessonsFragment.replaceFragment(LessonsFragment.java:126)
            at com.cbsystematic.mobile.itvdn.LessonsFragment.onDetach(LessonsFragment.java:119)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1954)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:313)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onDestroy(ActionBarActivity.java:169)
            at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6112)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3658)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3889)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I need to save state of current Fragment.

Fragment class code:

```
public class LessonsFragment extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {


private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

/**
 * The fragment's ListView.
 */
private AbsListView mListView;

/**
 * The Adapter which will be used to populate the ListView/GridView with
 * Views.
 */
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
private static String courseUrl;
private ParserJson parserJson = new ParserJson();
private TextView descriptionTextView;
private DescriptionData descriptionData;


// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
public static LessonsFragment newInstance(String url) {
    LessonsFragment fragment = new LessonsFragment();
    courseUrl = url;
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public LessonsFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // TODO: Change Adapter to display your content
    mAdapter = new LessonsItemAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.lessons_list_item, parserJson.getLessons(courseUrl).getLessonsArray());
    descriptionData = parserJson.getLessons(courseUrl).getDescriptionData();
}

//    @Override
//    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
//        //No call for super(). Bug on API Level > 11.
//    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lessons_list, container, false);

    descriptionTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lessons_description);
    descriptionTextView.setText("Описание курса:\n" +
            descriptionData.getShortDescription());

    // Set the adapter
    mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ((AdapterView<ListAdapter>) mListView).setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Set OnItemClickListener so we can be notified on item clicks
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;

    //this occurs when we move out of this Fragment
    replaceFragment(CatalogFragment.newInstance(1));

}

private void replaceFragment (Fragment fragment){
    String backStateName =  fragment.getClass().getName();
    String fragmentTag = backStateName;
    boolean fragmentPopped = getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped && getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag) == null){ //fragment not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragmentTag);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (null != mListener) {
        mListener.onLessonFragmentInteraction(parserJson.getLessons(courseUrl).getLessonsArray().get(position).getId());
    }
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p/>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onLessonFragmentInteraction(String id);
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AuthorizationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".NavigationActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.cbsystematic.mobile.itvdn.AuthorizationActivity" >
        <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.cbsystematic.mobile.itvdn.AuthorizationActivity" />
         >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Fragment's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_lessons"
android:background="#FAF9F9"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.cbsystematic.mobile.itvdn.LessonsFragment">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lessons_description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#acacac" />

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/lessons_description"/>
```

I know that such problems are like pain in the neck. But please give your assumptions.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: your error causing `Activity`, not `Fragment`, due to log line `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity`. you are doing smth wrong in `Activity` in `onDestrony` (before `super`) or earlier, due to log line `Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It crashes because the fragment gets recreated everytime you change the orientation.

Add this line to your activity in the manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```